# sorting scores from a txt file into alphabetical order

Tags: python, sorting

i have made a program where it stores a score attached with a name in a txt file. However, i want to then print the alphabetical order of the name attached to the score. I have created a code but it only prints it out in the order that the names and scores were inputted into the file. I want them in alphabetical. Any help?

```
if class_==1:

    inputFile=open('class_1', 'r')
    lineList = inputFile.readlines()
    lineList.sort()
    print('The input in alphabetical order below :')
    for line in  sorted(lineList):
        print(line)
```

Comment: `sort()` function will do a in-place sort. So you don't need to sort again.

Comment: yeah, but it hasnt sorted it when printed

Comment: What is the format of your text file? Is it score then name or name then score? For the name include first and last and what order are they in. If it includes first and last do you want to sort by first name or last?

Comment: @vbranden it is like this with only first name,for example...tom:8,bill:5,mike:6,

Answer (score 1):

this should be simple then

**class_1**

```
tom:8
bill:5
mike:6
```

**python**

```
inputFile = open('scores.txt', 'r')
lineList = inputFile.readlines()
for line in sorted(lineList):
        print(line.rstrip());
```